# How can winusb.h with __in annotiations can be compiled under c?

Tags: c

When I try to compile (on windows xp, with visual c++ 6.0) a c (NOT A C++) program which has the winusb.h header file, I get problems with c++ annotations (__in) like:

```
__in  HANDLE DeviceHandle,
```

What do I need to get this compiled in c?

Thanks alot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ignore it (and the similar annoations):

```
#define __in 
#define __out
#define __in_opt
```